# "Leave Open" vote given by mistake

Tags: support

It is the second time it happens. I pressed by mistake the button "leave open" when examining a post in the *Close Votes* queue.

I did not find a way to change the vote (is there?). Are there alternative options to nullify a vote given by mistake?

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10430/84967

Answer (score 6):

I do not believe way to fully nullify the vote, no. You can always navigate to the question manually and vote to close it there. Although the vote to leave it open would still be around for the purposes of leaving the queue you still would have cast a close vote for it.

Overall I wouldn't worry about this too much. Even if you accidentally cast a leave open vote two other people have to agree with you for it to leave the queue. Though if it happens frequently you might think about whether you are clicking through the queue too fast.